# Control send in a Script doesn't work well

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a script by myself in a game and I have a problem with the script. My problem is in the lines of code like this:

```
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 4500
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
```

The problem is that the action is not sent while the game is in the background. But instead in these instructions it did work:

```
ControlSend, ahk_parent, 3, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 3800
```

I don't understand the problem with commanding a key down versus sending a key.

I leave here a sample of the code so that you can inspect it in case you find any errors.

```
ControlSend, ahk_parent, 3, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 3800
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep 4500
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 1000
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {down down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 1000
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {down up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 1250
ControlSend, ahk_parent, 2 , ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 0100
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {right down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 2000
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {right up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {down down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 0325
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {down up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {right down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 0325
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {right up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 0100
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z up}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 0100
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z down}, ahk_exe javaw.exe
sleep, 2000
Loop, 6
{
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, 1 , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    sleep, 14000
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z down} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z up} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    sleep, 0100
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z down} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z up} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    sleep, 0100
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z down} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z up} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    sleep, 0100
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z down} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {z up} , ahk_exe javaw.exe
    sleep, 12900
}
return
```

I have to say that all the script with Send works correctly, only now I wanted to improve it so that it works in the background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never work **in the background** using *autohotkey* or the like (accessing the keyboard or mouse) because those UIDs only ever interact with the active window (the exception being software for instance to scroll an inactive window with the mouse wheel - but even then, you have to be *over the specific program* and can't have the mouse doing something else).

You need a COM interface or api to access to the underlying control element itself. What does Window Spy tell you about the control and contents?

Sorry but if it were that easy the games would find better ways to block AHK and other macro programs from the outset, but good luck in finding a solution (can you run a parallel instance that you can keep active in a virtual machine?)

Comment: I had never thought of using the script in a virtual machine where I leave the program open, I think that this solves the problem I have. And about the api and the com interfaces I will have to investigate, since I am a bit lost as this is my first script. Thank you very much for the solution.